# Strange issues when scrolling webpage in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

My website works flawlessly in Mozilla, Opera, IE etc., but in Chrome there are some issues. The menu and SoMe icons should stay fixed at the top when scrolling.

But when I scroll, the menu and SoMe icons acts weirdly (sometimes doesn't even follow scrolling), and the background in the centered main div, gets some glitches (lines of transparency). Any ideas?

Here's the frontpage of my website: http://blackforest.no/~vyrju/

Comment: You have similar glitches in FF too.

Comment: No problem at my FF ver. 33.1. Only Chrome.

Comment: You have jumping when changing top Menu to fixed, use fine scrolling (not by mouse wheel).

Comment: Ah, yes, that's in other browsers as well. I might live with that.

Comment: Thanks for noticing btw, @skobaljic. Just gave you a vote for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is video in background, it has negative `z-index`, change it to:

```
#video_background {
    z-index: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `backface-visibility: hidden;` to your `body` CSS. Vendor prefix it if it's only affecting chrome.

Comment: Kinda working, but I get another weird duplicate of my scroll bar inside the webpage. Like it was an iframe or something.

Comment: No issues here on Chrome after you updated. Try setting it on individual elements as needed. And adjust z-indexes. If you're using CSS transforms anywhere, be sure to zero out the Z value as well.

Comment: I guess I had already changed to @skobaljic's suggestion when you tested.